# curl in bash returns command not found

Tags: bash, curl

I have a very simple bash script in which I want to call curl and pass it to variable, this is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

mycommand = "$(curl 'https://...')"
sleep 2
echo "$mycommand"
```

and yet, when I call it it returns

```
./testScripttry.sh: line 3: mycommand: command not found
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Q: What happens if you eliminate the spaces and substitute "backtick" syntax: `mycommand=\`curl https://...\``?  Q: What happens if you try `let mycommand=...`?

Comment: If you remove the spaces around = it should work.

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) automatically detects this and other common problems